Исправление отображения заголовков у приложения
Мне нужно было сделать для диссертации список приложения. Мой итоговый вариант выглядит так:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}

% Настройка заголовков подразделов
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1em}
    {}

\titleclass{\section}{top}
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\newcounter{appendixsectioncount}
\setcounter{appendixsectioncount}{0}

\newcommand{\incrementAppendixSection}{
    \stepcounter{appendixsectioncount}
}

\appto{\appendix}{
    \renewcommand\thesection{\Asbuk{section}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\Asbuk{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    
    \titleformat{\section}
        {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}
        {Приложение \thesection}
        {1em}
        {}
    \settocdepth{section}
}

\preto{\appendix}{
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}{\incrementAppendixSection\oldsection}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Введение}
Текст введения.

\appendix

\section{Самый длинный заголовок приложения}
Текст приложения А.

\section{Некоторое приложение}
Текст приложения Б.

\end{document}

Но проблема заключается в том, что в содержании не отображается слово "приложение", и при длинном заголовке приложения текст не переносится корректно на новую строку.


Как исправить это?
